# New to programming, need help regarding if - elif input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm new here and I'm self teaching python to myself. Here's a code I've written so far. I'm trying to get a random input from the user. However, I don't understand which command to pass in if statement.

```
user = input("Enter your name: ")

for n in user:
    if user == input(user);
    print ('Name Entered')

else:
    print('Enter a name.')
```

Thanks.

[Edit]: Sorry for the trouble. So I've basically seen examples where we type names in the list and then carry on with if statement. I'm trying to make a code where a user inputs a random name and upon entering the name the result comes out as ' Name Entered ' else ' Enter a name' if there is no input provided by the user.

Comment: `for n in user` will loop through each character in the input `user`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do here. Please post a description of what you're trying to accomplish along with your code.

Comment: This can't be the actual code as Python doesn't use semicolons to mark the start of code blocks, it uses colons.

Comment: What is `if user == input(user)` supposed to do?  Are you trying to ask the user for more input, and comparing that against the first input?

Comment: You got the input, in the first line, and saved it in the variable `user`. What exactly are you trying to check `user` against?

Comment: What do you want the check for? Whether the user has entered a name? Or against any specific name? What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the user has typed any text as input. In python 3.x:

```
user = input("Enter your name: ")

if user:
    print ('Name Entered')
else:
    print('Enter a name.')
```

Comment: As a further explanation to OP: this works because `user` will be equal to `''`, or the  empty string. The empty string is *falsey*, which means that in a boolean check it will behave as though it is the boolean value `False`. Non-empty strings are *truthy*, which is the opposite - if treated as booleans, they behave as `True`. You could substitute the condition `if user:` with `if len(user) > 0:` to get a similar effect - checking if the string is non-empty, by checking how many characters it contains.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Before I delve into the coding side, I would like to call some attention the logic in your code. It seems to me that you would like to:

1. Take some form of user input
2. Verify that the user has provided an input ( this is what I am unsure about)
3. If they have, print their name to the console
4. If they haven't, prompt them to enter a name again

This can be done a multitude of ways. I will illustrate an example of using a while loop. This will make such that the program will continue to prompt the user for a name until they enter one.

```
user = ''

while len(user) <= 0:
    user = input("Enter your name: ")

print (str(user))
```

Comment: `while len(user) >= 0` will get you an infinite loop. It should be `while len(user) == 0`.

Comment: @A Webster, I think `while not user` looks a little nicer than `while len(user) <= 0` just because the exact length doesn't matter, just whether the string is null or not, plus the length couldn't be less than 0 anyway.

Comment: Hey guys sorry for not being too clear. I have changed my question to further explain what is needed. However, I got the solution. All I had to do was `if user:`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of syntax errors here and this will work fine if you fix them.  You don't need a for loop in this case since you only have one statement you are working through.  You also should use a colon, rather than a semi-colon after an if statement.  Additionally, indentation matters in python so you need to make sure your print statement is indented another level if you want it to be dependent on the if statement.  Something like this will work for receiving a user input and printing it if they provide one.  The following is sufficient for the task this code is accomplishing.

```
user = input("Enter your name: ")

if user == input(user):
    print ('Name Entered')

else:
    print('Enter a name.')
```

The for loop is only necessary if you need to iterate through a collection of values.  For example:

```
users=["Bob", "Sarah", "Anne", ""]

for user in users:
    if len(user) > 0:
        print (user)

    else:
        print('Enter a name.')

Output>>>Bob
         Sarah
         Anne
         Enter a name.
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking your time out, turns out I was unclear with my question. I have corrected my question and also got the solution above. Thank you and I apologize for the incomplete question.